# Sumar los números que muestra mi resultado

Tags: python

Tengo un ejercicio de Python que consiste en entrar un número entero, ejemplo `3`, debo imprimir `3` al cubo, es decir `3*3*3 = 27` y mostrar los números impares. Luego debo tomar 3 números impares y sumarlos para que también de como resultado `27`. Ya tengo la primera parte pero no se como hacer la parte de la suma.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora, solo muestro el valor del cubo ingresado y los números impares. Pero además necesito hacer una suma de `n` cifras que de como resultado el mismo valor de cube.

```
n = int (input("Entre un numero entero:")) 
cube = n ** 3 
print (cube) 
for i in range(1, cube, 2): 
print (i)
```

Comment: hola, mira [ask], debes mostrarnos que hiciste hasta ahora y donde fallo lo que probaste para la otra parte.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración. Bueno, esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora, solo muestro el valor del cubo ingresado y los números impares. Pero además necesito hacer una suma de n cifras que de como resultado el mismo valor de cube.

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.
 
n = int (input("Entrez un nombre entier:"))
cube = n ** 3
print (cube)
for i in range(1, cube, 2):
        print (i)

Answer (score 1):

Tienes las siguientes opciones:

Si `n^3 = 2k+1` , con k impar, entonces debes imprimir `k`, `k-2` y `3`.

```
k=n**3-1/2 % 2
if k == 1:
    print(f"Numbers: {k} + {k-2} + {3} == {n**3}")
```

Si `n^3 = 2(k)+1`, con `k` par, entonces debes imprimir `k-1`, `k-3` y `5`.

```
if k == 1:
    print(f"Numbers: {k} + {k-2} + {3} == {n**3}")
```

En general, para el primer caso puedes imprimir `k-t`, `k-m` y `1 + t+m`, donde `t`,`m` deben ser impares elegidos aleatoreamente en un rango adecuando para que `k-t`, `k-m` y `1 + t+m` no te salgan negativos, puedes usar `random.choice([i for i in range(1,k,2)])` para obtener un impar aleatorio entre `1` y `k`.
Un enfoque similar puede ser aplicado al segundo caso.

Comment: Procura que tus respuestas incluyan un fragmento de código explicando como usar tu respuesta. Sobre lo segundo, claro que se puede, selecciona el fragmento y le das `ctrl`+`k` (o lo encierras con triple backtick  ``` )

Comment: @Alfabravo, gracias, agregaré algo de código. Pero `Ctrl` + `k` hace segmentos de código y no texto en `LaTeX.`

Comment: Es lo más que tenemos, al marcarlo como código, el intérprete intenta identificar el lenguaje y colorear. COmo mínimo se identifica el bloque LaTeX y no se pierde nada por verse como texto común y corriente.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
import itertools

n = int(input("Entre un numero entero:"))
cube = n ** 3
print "Cube: %d" % cube

# Generar numeros impares
lst = [i for i in range(1, cube, 2)]

# Generar combinaciones
combs = []
for i in xrange(1, len(lst)+1):
    els = [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(lst, i)]
    combs.extend(els)

# Imprimir las combinaciones que sumen igual al cubo
for x in combs:
    sum = 0
    for y in x:
        sum += y
    if sum == cube:
        print "Combinacion: %s" % x
```

Eso te dará como resultado todas las combinaciones que al sumarlas producen un resultado igual al cubo:

```
Entre un numero entero:3
Cube: 27
Combinacion: [1, 3, 23]
Combinacion: [1, 5, 21]
Combinacion: [1, 7, 19]
Combinacion: [1, 9, 17]
Combinacion: [1, 11, 15]
Combinacion: [3, 5, 19]
Combinacion: [3, 7, 17]
Combinacion: [3, 9, 15]
Combinacion: [3, 11, 13]
Combinacion: [5, 7, 15]
Combinacion: [5, 9, 13]
Combinacion: [7, 9, 11]
Combinacion: [1, 3, 5, 7, 11]
```

La parte importante es el uso de itertools.combinations que genera todas las combinacions posibles de la lista de números impares. Luego es cuestión de iterar esas combinaciones y sumar los elementos para ver cual coincide con el cubo.